# prevent Windows .bat file from quiting

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a very simple Windows .BAT file:

```
set PATH=c:\xxx;%PATH%
call foo.pl
set VAR=true
```

I thought "`call`" will start a new batch process, without affecting the current one. However, the batch file exited immediately after the `foo.pl` finished executing. The `set VAR=true` has never been called.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: How do you figure out that `set VAR=true` was never called?

Comment: As you said, "call" will start a new **batch** process, _not_ a Pearl one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**foo.pl** is not a batch file, it is a Perl script.

So you need to use

```
path c:\xxx;%PATH%
"Path to\Folder With\perl.exe" "foo.pl"
rem Additional batch code executed after Perl script execution finished.
```

In other words you have to run the console application `perl.exe` best with full path, or with just `perl.exe` if program files folder of Perl is not the same on all computers on which this batch file is used and hopefully **PATH** contains also the directory containing `perl.exe`.

If you specify on a command line or in a batch file just **foo.pl**, Windows looks in Windows registry which application is associated with **.pl** for action *Open*. If there is such a file association, Windows runs this application in a separate process like when using command [start](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx).

So using `call foo.pl` is like using `start foo.pl`.

**PATH** is not only an environment variable, but also an interal command written for changing the value of environment variable **PATH** at any time within a batch file. This is the reason why I removed `set` from first line. It is better to use internal command `path` for modifying environment variable **PATH**.

Comment: I'm not aware of any functional difference between `path ...` vs. `set path=...`. Both `path` and `set` are internal commands, so I can't see why one is better than the other.

Comment: There is indeed no functional difference except with `set "PATH=..."` it is possible to add a directory path with special characters like `&` by using double quotes while with `path ...` it is necessary to escape `&` with `^` because double quotes can't be used with `path`. My choice of word with *better* was not good. I prefer `path` over `set PATH=` because of 4 less characters and better syntax highlighting in text editor. (The word `path` is always highlighted in my editor as internal command even after command `set` except when enclosed in percentage signs or in double quotes.)